# Extending XUnit Assert class with new asserts

Tags: c#, extension-methods, assert, xunit.net

I'm trying to extend the xUnit assert method by adding some selenium functionality

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Specs.PageLibrary.Extensions
{
    public static class AssertExtensions
    {
        public static void ElementPresent(this Assert assert, ...)
        {
            if (...)
            {
                throw new AssertException(...);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this compile error when I try to use it.

```
using MyProject.Web.Specs.PageLibrary.Extensions;    
using Xunit;
...

public void DoSomething()
{
    Assert.ElementPresent(...);
}
```

And the error

```
Error   5   'Xunit.Assert' does not contain a definition for 'ElementPresent'
```

Does anyone know if this is possible or where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need object intance that will be passed as this argument to extension method.
In your case this would be correct syntax

```
var assert = new Assert();
assert.ElementPresent(...);
```

But I suppose you don't need or even can't create instance of Assert class.

What you are trying to do is call extension method as static invocation on extended class and that wont work.
But why not simply call

```
 AssertExtensions.ElementPresent(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I couldn't get the assert to extend like I wanted.  Your solution is pretty much what I ended up doing, but I called mine `SeleniumAssert.ElementPresent(...);`

Comment: For xUnit 2, check out the examples such as https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/AssertExtensions/StringAssertionExtensions.cs

Comment: This won't work because `Assert`'s constructor is `protected`.

Answer (score 15):

**Edit 2** xUnit 2 eventually ended up moving the assertions into a separate assembly altogether. There are both compiled and source only packages of this on NuGet, and the `Assert` class is partial, so by using the source only version of the package, `Assert` becomes very easily extensible (in C#, that is).

**Edit** For more completeness: xUnit 2 removes this extension point and recommends using extension methods along the lines of 'fluent' assertion libraries.

---

For completeness, here's a description of the "official" way of extending `Assert` (which surprisingly has not been mentioned at all, despite the fact that Brad Wilson even joined the discussion).

From version 1.5 (according to Brad's blog), xUnit.Extensions has explicit support for this via the `Assertions` and `TestClass` classes. It works like this:

`TestClass` has a property called `Assert` that is of type `Assertions` which relays all the methods on `Xunit.Assert`. Because `TestClass.Assert` is an instance, you can add methods to it through extension methods on `Assertions`:

```
public static class AssertionsExtensions
{
    public static void DeepEquals(this Assertions assertions, XNode expected, XNode actual)
    {
        assertions.True(XNode.DeepEquals(expected, actual)); // You can also use Assert.True here, there's effectively no difference.
    }
}
```

Now you need to have your test class derive from `Xunit.Extensions.TestClass` (confusingly, there is also `Xunit.TestClass`, which is not what you want), and the `Assert` property will "shadow" the `Xunit.Assert` type if you don't qualify the name explicitly.

In your test class that derives from `TestClass`, you can now use

```
Assert.DeepEquals(expectedXml, actualXml);
```

The only real difference from a built-in xUnit assertion (apart from the fact that syntax coloring for `Assert` is that of an identifier, not a type) is that when it fails, you simply get a `TrueException`, not a specific `DeepEqualsException` that could hypothetically tell you *where* the comparison failed. But of course you could build that too in the very same way.

Comment: Have a look at Ruben Bartelink's post.. below. Together with the knowledge up here it results in creating your own derivatoin from global::XUnit.Assert

Comment: And for xUnit 2, the easiest thing is to check out the examples such as https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/AssertExtensions/StringAssertionExtensions.cs

Answer (score 15):

Summary of the solution for **xUnit 2**. (Worked for me for version 2.1.0 from NuGet.)

Assert is a partial class that you can extend by adding another part. To be able to do that you need to compile the Assert assembly from sources. You can use `xunit.assert.source` NuGet to get the sources.

**The Steps**

1. **Remove** reference to the `xunit.assert` NuGet package from the project.
2. Instead install **`xunit.assert.source`** package.
3. In the `Xunit` namespace, define `public partial class Assert` and add your custom asserts there.
4. In your test project install the `xunit.extensibility.execution` package (or otherwise there will be a conflict between two different `Assert` classes and tests won't run becasue the `xunit.execution.*.dll` will be missing)

Example of a custom assert:

```
namespace Xunit
{ 
    public partial class Assert
    {
        public static void ArraySegmentEqual<T>(
            T[] expectedSequence, T[] buffer, int offset = 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < expectedSequence.Length; i++)
            {
                int b = i + offset;

                True(buffer[b].Equals(expectedSequence[i]),
                    $"Byte #{b} differs: {buffer[b]} != {expectedSequence[i]}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: *Other answers and edits also point to the solution, but it took me quite some tome to figure it out from there. Also, I do not claim this is the only or the best option.*

Comment: After you removing the xunit package it will stop running the test cases. Need to add xunit.core to up and running the test cases again.

Comment: Yes. Remove "xUnit", add "xUnit.Core" and "xUnit.Assert.Source".

Answer (score 13):

Sorry, but you're getting confused (EDIT: and so was I!). <strike>xUnit.net's `Assert` is `static` and thus cannot have extensions added (although other Assertion libraries do not sue this approach which is why one might expect to use Extension Methods to extend `Assert`). So in the xUnit.net universe, if you want to add a custom assertion, add a new static class with a different name.</strike>

You can make your approach work by changing your class from:

```
public static class AssertExtensions
{
    public static void ElementPresent(this Assert assert, ...)
```

to:

```
public class AssertExtensions : XUnit.Assert
{
    public static void ElementPresent(...)
```

and then using [Brad Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554/brad-wilson)'s trick of adding:

```
using Assert = MyProject.Web.Specs.PageLibrary.Extensions.AssertExtensions;
```

at the top of any file needing your extensions.

This technique is handy for adding overloads come to think of it....

(The obvious weakness is that you can't have more than one directly accessible via `Assert.` though)

Comment: The `Assert` class isn't static but the methods inside are static, that's what was throwing me off. See the solution for @jure

Comment: @Neil. Thanks for the downvote. I'm conversing with @xunit re seeing if `Assert` can become a static class to avoid anyone else running into this (it's a surprise to me that it isnt as xUnit.net depends on .NET 2.0 which allows static classes and I cant think how the change could be breaking.)

Comment: @Neil Ah, seems it may have been left open to enable the extension trick described [here](https://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/15792). Finally, the reason why I was so sure it was `static` - Brad Wilson himself told me it was:- https://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/238521

Comment: Sorry perhaps it was a bit harsh.  +vote for the extra info though!

Comment: We consciously made Assert not be a static class so that it could support extensibility. You can add new assertions to a derived class and then always use the new class, perhaps via a using directive like: `using Assert = MyNamespace.MyAssert;`

Comment: @BradWilson Thanks for confirming that - once again there's not a lot in xUnit that isn't By Design :)

Comment: @Neil Incorporated an application of this technique into the answer. Have not compiled it - let me know how you get on (though there's still a lot to be said for keeping it simple and putting your own Assertions into a custom Assert class and using them via the real name so you can <strike>grep</strike>`Select-String` for them and/or tell them apart from xUnit.net built-ins.)

Comment: @RubenBartelink I think I'll stick with my SeleniumAssert class that I  am currently using, seems to be a neater solutiion and keeps it simple

Comment: Worked for me having the Namespace and name override and inheriting it from Assert. The unniceer thing is: Resharper puts up some twiggy lines to indicate that I do a static call using a member notion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of a simple encapsulation constraint:

Since the `Assert` class has the constructor set to `protected` you can't create an `Extension Method` for it, because you can't instantiate it.

So in order to extend `Assert`, you just have to inherit from it:

```
public class MyExtendedAssert : Assert
{
    public void ElementPresent(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And use:

```
MyExtendedAssert.ElementPresent(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

For **xUnit 2+**:

1. Add `xunit.assert.source` Nuget package to the project with extensions.
2. Create partial class definition:

```
namespace Xunit
{
  public partial class Assert
  {
    public static void ElementPresent(...)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple `partial` helper where I add `That` property so that I can easily build extensions anywhere else:

```
// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
namespace Xunit
{
    public partial class Assert
    {
        [CanBeNull]
        public static Assert That => default;
    }
}
```

Read [Premil's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36088382/235671) answer how to setup the projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the solution posted by @Premil to work, but I had to reference `xunit.core` rather than `xunit.extensibility.execution`.

Sample Visual Studio 2019 solution is located at https://github.com/groberts314/TestXUnitCustomAssertions.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `Xunit.Assert` and add additional static methods to your subclass.

I call my subclass `Assert` so that I don't need to rename any of the existing assertions and so I don't need to remember what my subclass's name is.

```cs
public class Assert : Xunit.Assert
{
    public static void DoesXyz()
    {
        // test for XYZ
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}
```

Then in your test:

```cs
public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanUseDoesXyz()
    {
        Assert.DoesXyz();
    }
}
```